# compareTo Method with Doubles[Double Cannot Be Dereferenced]

Tags: java, computer-science, compareto

Today I am working on a new program to find the cheapest pizza in a file full of data. i am completely stuck on one issue though, it is using the compareTo method. I created it in my resource class but I am not getting errors saying a double cannot be dereferenced, I looked this issue up and still have had no help. I am not the most advanced programmer and do not understand many of the complicated answers on other resources. My specifications for the program are as follows:

> B. CheapPizza.java
>   a. Objective – implement the Comparable interface in Pizza.java.
>   b. Assignment – Use the Pizza.java file you copied into Chapter 10. Implement the
>   Comparable interface and add a compareTo() method. This compareTo() should be used
>   to help you find the cheapest pizza in pizza.txt.
>   Write CheapPizza.java client class to test the new version of Pizza.java. CheapPizza will
>   read in the pizzas from the file and will keep track of the cheapest pizza by using the
>   compareTo() method. Create a Pizza object to hold the cheapest pizza and a Pizza object
>   to read in the pizzas from the file. Use compareTo() to compare the cheapest pizza to the
>   pizza read from the file. If the pizza read from the file is cheaper, change the cheapest
>   pizza.
>   a. Input – pizzas.txt file on Blackboard.
>   b. Output – should appear exactly in the format shown below:
>   The cheapest pizza: The 9 inch olive pizza will cost $7.99

The code for the compareTo method is at the bottom of my code, can someone please explain to me what I am doing incorrect? Thank you for your time, have a great day! ~

```
public class Pizza   {   
    private int size;
    private double cost;
    private String topping;

    public Pizza(int s, double c, String t)
    {
       size = s;
       cost = c;
       topping = t;
    }
    public Pizza(String t, int s, double c) //.equals Method For Comparing Pizza for ''PizzaMatch''
    {
       topping = t;
       size = s;
       cost = c;

    }

    public Pizza()
    {
       size = 10;
       cost = 9.00;
       topping = "Cheese";
    }

    public String toString()
    {
       return String.format("%d inch %s pizza will cost $%.2f", size, topping, cost);
    }
    public int getSize()
    {
       return size;
    }
    public void setSize(int s)
    {
       size = s;
    }

    public double getCost()
    {
       return cost;
    }
    public void setCost(Double c)
    {
       cost = c;  
    }
    public String getTopping()
    {
       return topping;   
    }
    public void setTopping(String t)
    {
       topping = t;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) //.equals Method For Comparing Pizza in "PizzaMatch"
    {
       if(!(obj instanceof Pizza)) 
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter must be of Pizza!");

       Pizza temp = (Pizza) obj;

       if (this.topping.equals(temp.topping) && this.size == temp.size  && this.cost == temp.cost)
          return true;
       else 
          return false;

    }
    //============================================================================================
    public int compareTo(Object obj){
        if(!(obj instanceof Pizza))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException
                ("Parameter must be a Pizza");
        Pizza temp = (Pizza) obj;  
        if (this.cost.compareTo(temp.cost) < 0) //this comes 1st
            return -1;
        else if(this.cost.compareTo(temp.cost) > 0) //temp comes 1st
            return 1;
        else //this and temp are equal
             return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't use `compareTo` with primitives, which `double`s are. Just compare them directly, e.g. `this.cost < temp.cost`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
       if(!(obj instanceof Pizza))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException
            ("Parameter must be a Pizza");
        Pizza temp = (Pizza) obj;  
        return Double.valueOf(this.cost).compareTo(Double.valueOf(temp.cost));
```

cost is primitive double. CompareTo is a method in object. So you can use Double object instead of double or You simple use arithmetic operation.

Comment: I appreciate the help, I was never taught this and I'm glad someone was able to explain this to me!

Answer (score 2):

`cost` is a field of the primitive type `double` and you cannot call methods (in your case `compareTo()`) on primitive types, only on objects. To compare two doubles, just compare them directly

```
 if (this.cost < temp.cost)
    return -1;
 else if(this.cost > temp.cost)
    return 1;
 else
    return 0;
```

Comment: This will fix the one error, but they'll still run into the issue of temp.cost being a private variable and unaccessible by the `compareTo` method.

Comment: No since it's also a method of the `Pizza` class and thus can access it's private variables.

Comment: Oh, I guess it can. My mistake

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement java.lang.Comparable interface to Pizza class

```
public class Pizza implements Comparator<Pizza> {
    // Enter other codes
    // with toString

   @Override
   public int compareTo(Pizza o) {
        return  Double.valueOf(this.cost).compareTo(Double.valueOf(o.cost));
   }
}
```

Then use Collections.sort( listOfPizzas ) to sort out pizzas according to the cost.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List l = new ArrayList();
    l.add(new Pizza(9, 7.99, "Olive Pizza"));
    l.add(new Pizza(9, 8.99, "Hot & Spicy Chicken Pizza"));
    l.add(new Pizza(9, 9.99, "Corned Mutton Sensation Pizza"));
    Collections.sort(l);
    System.out.println(" " + l.get(0));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know this new method of sorting the data, I appreciate it!